# SQL Date between and another condition statement not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is two SQL Query when executing this SQL its work fine.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM xyz 
 WHERE file_play_start_date BETWEEN '2011-07-01 06:15:00' 
                                AND '2011-07-08 06:30:00'
```

...but when adding another condition then its not working.
e.i:returning no result tho there is result to show in this condition.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM xyz 
 WHERE calender_id = 3 
   AND file_play_start_date BETWEEN '2011-07-01 06:15:00' 
                                AND '2011-07-08 06:30:00'
```

Can any one tell me why its happening?

Comment: Have you verified that there are records satisfying _both_ of those conditions? Also, it's spelled, "calendar."

Comment: Can you include all ther results from the first query?  It certainly appears that none of them have `calender_id=3`

Comment: Add `ORDER BY calender_id` to the first query, and confirm there are none whose `calender_id` value is 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no rows in xyz where calender_id = 3 and file_play_start_date between '2011-07-01 06:15:00' and '2011-07-08 06:30:00'.

Answer (score 3):

Because there are no records with `calendar_id` of 3 and the `file_play_start_date` between those two values.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from reqcat.tpa_log where pa_status_cd='BAD' and row_update_time BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-28';
```

Its not working . But when I do the

`count * with pa_status_cd='BAD' and   row_update_time BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-28'`

seperately it works.